# Learning to create basic a color assignment tool on wix's velo

Tags: javascript, java, velo

In the image below is the screenshot of my wix editor where i'm trying to create a basic color assigner which is supposed to assign the big box the color of the button that is clicked by someone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWHBV.png)

Please review and see why the code i am using is not working.
Here is the code;

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    // Selectors for all the Container boxes
    const bigBox = $w('#box0');
  const boxColor = bigBox.style.backgroundColor;
  const firstButton = $w('#button1');
  const firstcolor = firstButton.style.backgroundColor;
    const secondButton = $w('#button2');
  const secondColor = secondButton.style.backgroundColor;
    const thirdButton = $w('#button3');
  const thirdColor = thirdButton.style.backgroundColor;
    const fourthButton = $w('#button4');
  const fourthColor = fourthButton.style.backgroundColor;


    firstButton.onClick(event => {
     boxColor = firstcolor;
     });
    secondButton.onClick(event => {
      boxColor = secondColor;
     })
    thirdButton.onClick(event => {
      boxColor = thirdColor;
    })
    fourthButton.onClick(event => {
      boxColor = fourthColor;
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the color to the box the way you are trying to do it. What you are currently doing is storing the initial value of the box in a variable and then just changing the value of that variable. When you change the variable, it will not do anything to the box. Instead, you need to actually change the value of the box's `backgroundColor`.

So the bottom section of your code should look something like this:

```
firstButton.onClick(event => {
  bigBox.style.backgroundColor = firstcolor;
});
secondButton.onClick(event => {
  bigBox.style.backgroundColor = secondColor;
})
thirdButton.onClick(event => {
  bigBox.style.backgroundColor = thirdColor;
})
fourthButton.onClick(event => {
  bigBox.style.backgroundColor = fourthColor;
})
```

And you can get rid of this line on the top:

```
const boxColor = bigBox.style.backgroundColor;
```